# Find all singularities of a function and determine its types

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

> Find all singularities of a function and determine its types
>
> $$f(z)=\frac{e^{iz}-1}{\sin{z}}e^{\frac{1}{z}}$$

I already showed, that $f$ has poles at points $z=\pi n$ where $n\in\mathbb{Z}\setminus \{0\} $.

I suspect it has essential singularity at $0$ but I can't show it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint.** Recall that, **for $z$ near $0$**, you have an essential singularity at $0$ for
$$
e^{\frac{1}{z}}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}\frac{1}{z^n}, \tag1
$$
now, with
$$
h(z):=\frac{e^{iz}-1}{\sin{z}} , \quad h(0)=i\neq 0,\tag2
$$ you have$$ f(z)=h(z)\:e^{\frac{1}{z}} $$  then $f(z)$ has an essential singularity at $0$ from $(1)$ and $(2)$.

Comment: So we can split this function in two parts? What is the reasoning behind this? Thanks

Comment: @luka5z We just express our function as the product of a non vanishing function by a function with an essential singularity, the result is a function with an essential singularity, you may readily see this by Taylor's expansion near $0$. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Note that for $z=\pi n$, $n$ even, $n\neq0$, both nominator and denominator have simple zeros. Hence, the function has removable singularities at these points.

For $z=0$, you can use the power series expansion of $e^z$ to show this is an essential singularity.

Comment: When $n$ is odd integer the nominator doesnt have $0$, does it? But function has limit in 0 then so it is in fact removable singularity.

Comment: @luka5z At odd integers the nominator does not vanish, so the function has poles. At $0$, it is an essential singularity.